# How to select a checkbox for a div using cypress?

Tags: reactjs, cypress

i have  html content like below,

```
<div role="row" data-testid="table-row-0">
    <div role="cell">
        <input  data-testid="table-row-checkbox" type="checkbox" checked> //uncheck this                checkbox
        <label></label>
    </div>
    <div role="cell">name1</div> //find by this name1
    <div role="cell">type1</div>
</div>
<div role="row" data-testid="table-row-1">
    <div role="cell">
        <input  data-testid="table-row-checkbox" type="checkbox" checked>
        <label></label>
    </div>
    <div role="cell">name2</div>
    <div role="cell">type2</div>
</div>
```

as seen from above, i want to uncheck the checkbox for the div with name1. how can i do it using cypress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`uncheck`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/uncheck) method:

```js
cy.contains('name1').parent().find('input').uncheck()
```

Comment: but we have two checkboxes with data-testid table-row-checkbox. i want to get the one for div with name1

Comment: Updated my answer to use a selector which uses `contains` to find the `div` with `name1` text and then uses `parent` to get the checkbox within the common parent.

Comment: .get() will always search within cy.root element. https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get#Get-vs-Find

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way to get the correct input.

```js
cy.contains('[data-testid^=table-row-]','name1')
  .find('[data-testid=table-row-checkbox]')
  .uncheck()
```

Here is working [example](https://github.com/jjhelguero/cypress-examples/commit/9038587706f52daa77f2b003d028f42ba6abf188).